# How to get a list of twitter usernames that begins with a particular character or string

Tags: .net, twitter, tweetinvi

Is there a way using the twitter api to generate a list of usernames that match whatever character(s) comes after a user types '@'?  I want to implement the autocompletion that happens in  the Twitter app when you're creating a tweet and you type @.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the user search endpoint of the Twitter REST API (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search).

In Tweetinvi you can do that with the following code :

```
var users = Search.SearchUsers("tweetin");
```

Note that this endpoint is limited to 180 requests every 15 minutes.